# Discord bot, how to write messages with different names and avatar?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I saw in a discord community that they can write messages with a single bot, with different names and avatar. I know that discord has a limit to change your username, but also if you change the Nickname for just that discord community, all the previous messages that the bot did write, also change the nickname, which is not the case in this discord community.

[Screenshot of how this looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhBUn.png)

So far, I did try to change the username (but because of the username change rate limit I can't do it again) and also the nickname:

```
const main = async (c: Client<boolean>) => {
  const guild = c.guilds?.cache.get(GUID)
  const channel = c.channels.cache.get(CID);
  const bot = c.user;
  if (!bot) return;
  if (!guild) return;
  if (!channel) return;
  if (channel.type !== ChannelType.GuildText) return;

  await guild.members.cache.get(bot.id)?.setNickname("User 1")
  const message = await channel.send("Hi there everyone");

  await guild.members.cache.get(bot.id)?.edit({nick: "User 2"})
  channel.send("doing fine");

  await guild.members.cache.get(bot.id)?.setNickname("User 3")
  channel.send("yeah!");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoe need to use webhooks not discord bot. To that webhook you will import avatar and name what you want. Send with it message. Than webhook delete.

Webhook discord.js guide:
https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/webhooks.html#creating-webhooks-through-server-settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).